# Can I send a signal to a method I call indirectly without changing the methods in between?

Tags: ruby

I have a `view` which aggregates the result of running a complex computation several times with different inputs. This computation relies on a couple of base methods which are sometimes, but not always, very expensive (on a cache miss). The following is a working example of roughly this situation:

```
def view
    10.times.map do
        complicated_process_with_many_methods
    end
end

def complicated_process_with_many_methods
    [sometimes_expensive_method, sometimes_expensive_method]
end

def sometimes_expensive_method
    if rand < 0.5
        "expensive result"
    else
        "inexpensive result"
    end
end

puts view
```

However, sometimes the user just wants to see whatever data we can fetch quickly, and doesn't want to wait a long time for the data that would have to be computed. That is, we should render as much of `view` as we can without depending on an expensive invocation of `sometimes_expensive_method`. sometimes_expensive_method can easily determine if this will be an expensive invocation or not, but the information required to do so should not be available to `view` or to `complicated_process_with_many_methods`.

I would like to be able to call `complicated_process_with_many_methods` in such a way that, if ever `sometimes_expensive_method` turns out to be expensive, we give up and use a default value for that invocation of `complicated_process_with_many_methods`. However, if nothing turns out to be expensive, then the real result of `complicated_process_with_many_methods` should be used.

I could add a flag which causes `sometimes_expensive_method` to behave differently when the result would be expensive:

```
def sometimes_expensive_method(throw_on_miss)
    if rand < 0.5
        if throw_on_miss
            raise ExpensiveResultException
        else
            "expensive result"
        end
    else
        "inexpensive result"
    end
end
```

then catch that exception in `view` and use a default value instead. However, this would require passing that flag through all of the different methods involved in `complicated_process_with_many_methods`, and I feel like those methods should not have to know about this behavior. I could instead have `sometimes_expensive_method` call a continuation when the result would be expensive, but that continuation would also have to be passed through all the calls. I don't think a global would help, because different requests may invoke the different behaviors at the same time.

What I'm looking for is some way for `sometimes_expensive_method` to change its behavior (perhaps by throwing an exception) in response to some sort of signal that is defined in `view`, without modifying the body of `complicated_process_with_many_methods` to pass the signal along. Does such a signal exist in ruby?

Comment: Please put backticks around method names (and whatever else that are raw code) in the text so that it looks `like this`. It makes it easier to read. Also, there would be more people responding if you can make the question more concise.

Comment: If you can predict whether calling `sometimes_expensive_method` will be expensive or not outside `sometimes_expensive_method`, then just wrap those expensive methods into a proxy method, or just redefine (or refine if possible) those methods. Otherwise you have to rewrite those methods.

Comment: @Aetherus I cannot predict whether the call will be expensive or not outside `sometimes_expensive_method`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Timeout`. [See here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html).
I don't know if it will release the external resources (files or db connections), so use it at your own risk.